# reloading list after insert in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am performing insert and update, and after words I would like to reload the list of items, but it is duplicating it in the view.

Here is the load function

```
// Listing contact resources
    $scope.load = function () {
        var g = $rdf.graph();
        var f = $rdf.fetcher(g);

        f.nowOrWhenFetched($scope.path + '*',undefined,function(){  
            var DC = $rdf.Namespace('http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/');
            var RDF = $rdf.Namespace('http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#');
            var LDP = $rdf.Namespace('http://www.w3.org/ns/ldp#');
            //var myOntology = $rdf.Namespace('http://user.pds.org/ontology/'); 
            var VCARD = $rdf.Namespace('http://www.w3.org/2006/vcard/ns#');

            var evs = g.statementsMatching(undefined, RDF('type'), VCARD('Individual'));
            if (evs != undefined) {
                for (var e in evs) {
                    var id = evs[e]['subject']['value'];
                    var fullname = g.anyStatementMatching(evs[e]['subject'], VCARD('fn'))['object']['value'];
                    var email = g.anyStatementMatching(evs[e]['subject'], VCARD('hasEmail'))['object']['value'];
                    var phone = g.anyStatementMatching(evs[e]['subject'], VCARD('hasTelephone'))['object']['value'];

                    var contact = {
                        id: id.slice(id.length-1),
                        fullname: fullname,
                        email: email,
                        phone: phone 
                    };
                    $scope.contacts.push(contact);
                    $scope.$apply();
                }
            }
        });
    };
```

Here is the insert/update function

```
    // Function to insert or update a contact resource
    $scope.insertContact = function (contact) {
        var uri = $scope.path + $scope.prefix + contact.id;
        var resource = $scope.composeRDFResource(contact, uri);
        $http({
          method: 'PUT', 
          url: uri,
          data: resource,
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'text/turtle',
            'Link': '<http://www.w3.org/ns/ldp#Resource>; rel="type"'
          },
          withCredentials: true
        }).
        success(function(data, status, headers) {
          if (status == 200 || status == 201) {
            console.log('Success: Resource created.');
            // Update view
            $scope.load();
          }
        }).
        error(function(data, status) {
          if (status == 401) {
            console.log('Forbidden: Authentication required to create new resource.');
          } else if (status == 403) {
            console.log('Forbidden: You are not allowed to create new resource.');
          } else {
            console.log('Failed '+ status + data);
          }
        });
    };
```

Both work properly, but when calling the load in the insert it adds the new items reloaded along with the old once in the list already.

Where to empty the list before/during the reload?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should empty the list just before 'loading in' new items.

```
.success(function(data, status, headers) {
    if (status == 200 || status == 201) {
        console.log('Success: Resource created.');
        // Update view
        $scope.contacts.length = 0;
        $scope.load();
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can empty contact list on beginning your $scope.load function ie:

```
$scope.load = function () {
    //here
    $scope.contacts = []
    var g = $rdf.graph();
    var f = $rdf.fetcher(g);
    ...
}
```

but I will advise you to add new contact only to list instead of reloading all list after update in your success call back

```
success(function(data, status, headers) {
              if (status == 200 || status == 201) {
                console.log('Success: Resource created.');
                // Update view
                //instated of reloading all list
                //$scope.load();
                //just add new contact
                $scope.push(contact)
}


   }
```

Comment: This I tried, but it dosn't renders an empty list in the view

Comment: @Magini and what is rendered ?

Comment: Sorry I meant to say that it renders an empty list instead! Solution above worked.